# Move selection to their respective column's bottom in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, selection, move

If I have data in 5 columns (A-F) and I select different cells within those columns, I'd like a macro that would move the contents of these cells to their respective columns 12th row.

Egs.: A3,B2,B4,C4,D1,D2,F4
The contents of these should go to A12,B12,C12,D12,F12 separated by a ", ".

This almost does the job, but it doesn't work if I select stuff from more than 1 column:

```
Sub Move()

Dim selectedCells As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim values() As String
Dim CSV As String

Set selectedCells = Selection
ReDim values(selectedCells.Count - 1)

i = 0
For Each rng In selectedCells
    values(i) = CStr(rng.Value)
  i = i + 1
Next rng

CSV = Join(values, ", ")

Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Selection.Address(True, False), "$")
SC = vArr(0)

Range(SC & "12").Value = CSV
Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `Selection` is discouraged, but if you want to take that approach, what about something like this?

```
Sub Move()

Dim selectedCells As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim targetRng As Range

Set selectedCells = Selection

For Each rng In selectedCells
    Set targetRng = Cells(12, rng.Column)
    If IsEmpty(targetRng) Then
        targetRng = rng
    Else
        targetRng = targetRng & ", " & rng
    End If
    rng.ClearContents
Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

another possibility:

```
Sub Move()
    Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range

    For Each cell In Selection
        With Cells(12, cell.Column)
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                For Each cell2 In Intersect(.EntireColumn, Selection)
                    .Value = .Value & " " & cell2.Value
                Next
                .Value = Join(Split(Trim(.Value), " "), ",")
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```